# Redirect email based on Source IP / Hostname

Tags: exchange-2007

So, we have a situation where we would like to be able to redirect (ignoring original destination) emails coming through out exchange server (locally sent) to a different email address.

The situation is as follows:
Testing a new server, this hosts a lot of our custom applications / scheduled tasks (as does the production version of this server). 
Instead of changing config files / parameters for these applications we'd rather leave them as they are, as we want to be as close to production as possible, however we don't want the emails go to the staff they would normally go to, we'd rather they were sent to a test email address where we are able to confirm the results.

The emails look exactly like the production emails (same from / to / cc / bcc) except their source, hence why we'd like to know if the ability to redirect based on hostname exists.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with Exchange 2007 by using **Transport Rules** in the Hub Transport role.  Add a new rule and set the condition trigger to "when the message header contains text patters".  The header field should be **Received** and the contains text will be the IP address of your sending server.

The action on the email you probably want to perform is "redirect the message to addresses".